# What natural forces can cause a volcano to erupt seasonally?

Tags: natural-disasters, volcanoes, seasons

Simply put, what forces of nature would cause a volcano to erupt on a seasonal basis? Say it does not do anything 9/12 months, but it becomes very active for three months and often erupts. I would like it to be a visible eruption (No Phreatomagmatic eruptions, please).

Any form of eruption is acceptable, but explosive eruption is preferred. I have several moons that can act as a catalyst, providing tidal forces that cause the said volcano to erupt a la the Jovian moon Io.

I am still learning to post properly, so forgive me for any errors. Please point them out as they appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said it already: tidal forces caused by an eccentric orbit, which brings the moon closer to the planet only for 1/4 of the orbital period, causing therefore deformation in the crust and increased volcanic activity all around.

Comment: Well, yes, but I wish to find ALL the potentials I can use, not just one. Expand my knowledge.

Comment: @Rory02 There is pretty much no other reason.

Comment: Well then. That settles that. I accidentally found the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Rory02 in addition, we normally do not brainstorm here. We work on a best answer principle. Asking a question can of course lead to new insights or other ideas, but asking a question for just new ideas is frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

It is believed that some volcanoes on Earth have seasonal variation in their activity (though there are many other factors too). As I understand it, the driving force for this is differences in tropical/monsoon rainfall; heavy rain increases the loading on the rock and acts (with some time delay?) as a lubricant and source of steam for the magma. (The processes involved are complex, and are definitely outside my expertise!)

Given that seasonal variation exists in reality (albeit at a statistical level), accentuating it in your constructed world is fine. Assume there is a mechanism by which it can be explained, and try to avoid going into the details.